# Java SocketChannel not receiving incoming data properly

Tags: java, server, channel

I'm writing a chat room server which takes message from a chat client and broadcasts out the message to all users. This is an exercise from a book called *An Introduction to Network Programming with Java: Java 7 Compatible* with which I'm self-teaching Java networking basics. I wrote a GUI frontend for the chat room and implemented the server backend, following examples from the code in the book. However, when I tested the code with chat clients, the server seemed unable to receive clients' data. I can't figure out why. The code for the chat room (here it was made in command line mode for test purpose) and the client is as followings. Thank you.

```
// code for the server backend, problem seems to be lie in here.


 /**
 * The multiecho server itself
 */
package channelEchoServer;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MultiEchoServerNIO {
    private static ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel;
    private static final int PORT = 1234;
    private static Selector selector;
    private static Vector<SocketChannel> socketChannelVec;
    private static Vector<ChatUser> allUsers;
    public static final int CAPACITY = 20;
    public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
    public static final String NEW_LINE = System.lineSeparator();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
            serverSocket = serverSocketChannel.socket();
            InetSocketAddress netAddress = new InetSocketAddress(PORT);
            serverSocket.bind(netAddress);
            selector = Selector.open();
            serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
        }
        catch (IOException ioEx) {
            ioEx.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        socketChannelVec = new Vector<>(CAPACITY);
        allUsers = new Vector<>(CAPACITY);
        System.out.println("Server is opened ...");
        processConnections();
    }

    private static void processConnections () {
        do {
            try {
                int numKeys = selector.select();
                System.out.println(numKeys + " keys selected.");
                if (numKeys > 0) {
                    Set eventKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
                    Iterator keyCycler = eventKeys.iterator();
                    while (keyCycler.hasNext()) {
                        SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey)keyCycler.next();
                        int keyOps = key.readyOps();
                        if ((keyOps & SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) == SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) {
                            acceptConnection(key);
                            continue;
                        }
                        if ((keyOps & SelectionKey.OP_READ) == SelectionKey.OP_READ) {
                            acceptData(key);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ioEx) {
                ioEx.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        } while (true);
    }
    private static void acceptConnection (SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        SocketChannel socketChannel;
        Socket socket;

        socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        socket = socketChannel.socket();
        System.out.println("Connection on " + socket + ".");
        socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        socketChannelVec.add(socketChannel);
        selector.selectedKeys().remove(key);
    }
    private static void acceptData (SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        SocketChannel socketChannel;
        Socket socket;

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);
        socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        buffer.clear();
        int numBytes = socketChannel.read(buffer);
        socket = socketChannel.socket();
        if (numBytes == -1) {
            key.cancel();
            closeSocket(socket);
        }
        else {
            String chatName = null;
            byte[] byteArray = buffer.array();
            if (byteArray[0] == '#')
                announceNewUser(socketChannel, buffer);
            else {
                for (ChatUser chatUser : allUsers)
                    if (chatUser.getUserSocketChannel().equals(socketChannel))
                        chatName = chatUser.getChatName();
                broadcastMessage(chatName, buffer);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void closeSocket (Socket socket) {
        try {
            if (socket != null)
                socket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioEx) {
            System.out.println("Unable to close socket!");
        }
    }
    public static void announceNewUser (SocketChannel userSocketChannel, ByteBuffer buffer) {
        ChatUser chatUser;
        byte[] byteArray = buffer.array();
        int messageSize = buffer.position();
        String chatName = new String(byteArray, 1, messageSize);
        if (chatName.indexOf("\n") >= 0)
            chatName = chatName.substring(0, chatName.indexOf("\n"));
        chatUser = new ChatUser(userSocketChannel, chatName);
        allUsers.add(chatUser);
        if (!socketChannelVec.remove(userSocketChannel)) {
            System.out.println("Can't find user!");
            return;
        } // we should save userSocketChannel in a chatUser instance before deleting it.
        chatName = chatUser.getChatName();
        System.out.println(chatName + " entered the chat room at " + new Date() +  "." + NEW_LINE);
        String welcomeMessage = "Welcome " + chatName + "!" + NEW_LINE;
        byte[] bytes = welcomeMessage.getBytes(); 
        buffer.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < welcomeMessage.length(); i++)
            buffer.put(bytes[i]);
        buffer.flip();
        try {
            chatUser.getUserSocketChannel().write(buffer);
        }
        catch (IOException ioEx) {
            ioEx.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void announceExit (String name) {
        System.out.println(name + " left chat room at " + new Date() + "." + NEW_LINE);
        for (ChatUser chatUser : allUsers) {
            if (chatUser.getChatName().equals(name))
                allUsers.remove(chatUser);
        }
    }
    public static void broadcastMessage (String chatName, ByteBuffer buffer) {
        String messagePrefix = chatName + ": ";
        byte[] messagePrefixBytes = messagePrefix.getBytes();
        final byte[] CR = NEW_LINE.getBytes();

        try {
            int messageSize = buffer.position();
            byte[] messageBytes = buffer.array();
            byte[] messageBytesCopy = new byte[messageSize];

            String userMessage = new String(messageBytes, 0, messageSize);
            if (userMessage.equals("Bye"))
                announceExit(chatName);

            for (int i = 0; i < messageSize; i++) 
                messageBytesCopy[i] = messageBytes[i];
            buffer.clear();
            buffer.put(messagePrefixBytes);
            for (int i = 0; i < messageSize; i++)
                buffer.put(messageBytesCopy[i]);
            buffer.put(CR);
            SocketChannel chatSocketChannel;
            for (ChatUser chatUser : allUsers) {
                chatSocketChannel = chatUser.getUserSocketChannel();
                buffer.flip();
                chatSocketChannel.write(buffer);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioEx) {
            ioEx.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class ChatUser {
    private SocketChannel userSocketChannel;
    private String chatName;

    public ChatUser (SocketChannel userSocketChannel, String chatName) {
        this.userSocketChannel = userSocketChannel;
        this.chatName = chatName;
    }

    public SocketChannel getUserSocketChannel () {
        return userSocketChannel;
    }
    public String getChatName () {
        return chatName;
    }
}

// Code for a chat client for testing purpose
    package multithreadEchoChatroomClientGUI;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MultithreadEchoChatroomClient1 {
    private static Socket socket;
    private static InetAddress host;
    private static String address;
    public static final int PORT = 1234;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        address = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the host name or IP address:");
        try {
            host = InetAddress.getByName(address);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException uhEx) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unknown Host!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            socket = new Socket(host, PORT);
        }
        catch (IOException ioEx) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ioEx.toString(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable () {
            public void run () {
                ClientFrame client = new ClientFrame(host, socket, address);
                client.setTitle("Chat");
                client.setSize(400, 500);
                client.setVisible(true);
                new Thread(client).start();
            }
        });
    }
}

class ClientFrame extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    private InetAddress host;
    private String address;
    private Socket socket;
    private Scanner input;
    private PrintWriter output;
    private JMenuItem connect;
    private JTextArea serverResponseArea;
    private JTextArea messageArea;
    private JTextField messageFiled;
    private JButton sendButton;
    private String serverResponse;
    private String clientName;

    public ClientFrame (InetAddress host, Socket socket, String address) {
        this.host = host;
        this.socket = socket;
        this.address = address;

        initFrame();
    }

    public void run () {

        try {
            input = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        }
        catch (IOException ioEx) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Cannot create input or output stream!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            closeSocket();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        do {
            clientName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What nickname would you like to use in the chatroom?");
        } while (clientName == null);
        output.println("#" + clientName);
        do {
            serverResponse = input.nextLine();  
            serverResponseArea.append(serverResponse + "\n");
        } while (socket.isClosed() != true);
    }

    private final void closeSocket () {
        try {
            socket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioEx) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Cannot disconnect from chatroom!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    private void initFrame () {
        JMenuBar menuBar = createMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JScrollPane responsePanel = createResponsePanel();
        add(responsePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel messagePanel = createMessagePanel();
        add(messagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //JPanel textPanel = createTextPanel();
        //add(textPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter () {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing (WindowEvent we) {
                if (!socket.isClosed())
                    closeSocket();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    private JMenuBar createMenuBar () {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Operations");
        connect = new JMenuItem("Connect");
        connect.setEnabled(false);
        connect.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    host = InetAddress.getByName(address);
                }
                catch (UnknownHostException uhEx) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unknown Host!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                try {
                    socket = new Socket(host, MultithreadEchoChatroomClient1.PORT);
                }
                catch (IOException ioEx) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ioEx.toString(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                try {
                    input = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                    output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                }
                catch (IOException ioEx) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ClientFrame.this, "Cannot create input or output stream!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    closeSocket();
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                output.println("#" + clientName);
                serverResponse = input.nextLine();
                serverResponseArea.append(serverResponse + "\n");
            }
        });
        JMenuItem quit = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
                if (!socket.isClosed())
                    closeSocket();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        menu.add(connect);
        menu.add(quit);
        menuBar.add(menu);

        return menuBar;
    }

    private JScrollPane createResponsePanel () {
        serverResponseArea = new JTextArea(20, 35);
        serverResponseArea.setEditable(false);
        serverResponseArea.setLineWrap(true);
        serverResponseArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        serverResponseArea.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JScrollPane scrlPane = new JScrollPane(serverResponseArea);
        scrlPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 10, 10, 20));
        scrlPane.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        return scrlPane;
    }

    private JPanel createMessagePanel () {
        JPanel msgPanel = new JPanel();

        msgPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,10, 10, 20));
        msgPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        msgPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(msgPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        JScrollPane srlPanel = createMessageTextPanel();
        msgPanel.add(srlPanel);

        JButton sdButton = createSendButton();
        msgPanel.add(sdButton);

        return msgPanel;
    }

    private JScrollPane createMessageTextPanel () {
        messageArea = new JTextArea(10, 35);
        //messageArea.setEditable(false);
        messageArea.setLineWrap(true);
        messageArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        messageArea.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        JScrollPane mtPanel = new JScrollPane(messageArea);

        return mtPanel;
    }

    private JButton createSendButton () {
        JButton button = new JButton("Send");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
                String message;

                message = messageArea.getText();
                System.out.println(message);
                output.println(message);
                if (message.equals("Bye")) {
                    closeSocket();
                    connect.setEnabled(true);
                }
                messageArea.setText(""); 
                //serverResponse = input.nextLine();
                //serverResponseArea.append(serverResponse + "\n");
            }
        });
        return button;
    }
}
```

Thank you again for taking so much trouble reading much code and giving suggestions!

Comment: Please remove all the iirrelevant GUI code and reduce this to a short simple example.

Comment: @user207421: Sorry for the GUI frontend. I've removed the whole GUI frontend and turned the backend into an stand-alone command line program for testing purpose. I didn't remove the GUI client because it may still be needed for testing the chat room server. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: The data in a `ByteBuffer` is bounded by `position()`. It isn't the the entire array. You need to remove the selected key from the selected key set in all cases around the select loop.

Comment: @user207421 Thank you. Your suggested solution works fine. I should have removed any old key so that new keys can be detected by select().

Comment: It is customary to put the remove inside the select loop rather than spattering it all over the accept/read/write methods. That way you only need one, and you aren't prone to perpetrating this bug.

Comment: @user207421: Thank you for your help. That's neat. I've improved the code accordingly. I think that bug is a good lesson which leads me to find out about some relevant concepts. However, it seems that I ended up not well understanding what I'd read in those materials. Fortunately, you pointed out my blind points. The example in the book which I followed when I wrote the above code does have a remove() call in the acceptData(SelectionKey) method, but I missed out that call when I was copying the code from the book by typing. However, that miss turned out to be a good opportunity for learning.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved according to @user207421. I should have put a `remove()` operation in the `else {}` block in the method `acceptData(SelectedKey key)` so that the old key associated with the `socketChannel` is removed from the selected key set for new incoming keys to be able to be detected.

I don't know whether my understanding of user207421's solution was right or not, but it did solve the problem for now. If anybody has any other ideas, please share your views.

Thank you again, user207421. And thank all visitors to this post for your attention.